# C++Builder 11.3 change TEdit to TButtonedEdit without deleting TEdit?

Tags: c++builder

I want to change an existing `TEdit` to a `TButtonedEdit`, can I just change it or is there cached information or other things in the C++ Builder that will cause issues (sorta like manually editing resources in older versions of Visual Studio resource editor).

If I can, does the project need to be closed or is it okay to actually change it with the project open?

Comment: There's a reference in the .dfm file. The easiest way to make this change would be to click the TEdit, delete it, and then add the TButtonedEdit and name it the same as the old TEdit (assuming, of course, that you used a name other than the default `Edit1` naming). Then use the Object Inspector's Events tab to wire up any events that you had already created for the TEdit.